# Display Image from web service in gridview populated by datatable. vb.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, web-services, gridview

Im trying to insert a series of images into a gridview from a datatable from a web service.
the images are currently being displayed as a string in url form.
what tags can I put around it so the urls are converted to images.
The gridview is populated dynamically so im unable to put each image in manually.
I know it can be done because Ive seen it work, but i cannot find the solution anywhere.

hope someone can help.
thanks

```
   dim grimlogo as string    
   grimlogo = datatable.Rows(i)("Logo").ToString()
   grimlogo = "IMG TAGS HERE" & grimlogo & "AND HERE"
   datatable.Rows(i)("Logo") = grimlogo
```

Ive tried something like this but it didnt work

heres the link to what im working on
http://heweb.grimsby.ac.uk/student/s0215538/Heathrow_Airport/allheathrowtrains.aspx

Comment: Show what you tried so far.

Comment: ive tried taking the url as a string and putting image tags around it and putting the new url back into the gridview but the tags I put in were just returned as a string with the url.

Comment: You have to show you code mate.

Comment: added code and a link to my project so far

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Insert a TemplateField into your Gridview. From there you can dynamically add an Image control to each row upon RowBound. You'll need to make sure the gridview is bound on every postback so the image isn't lost. You'll also need to set the AlternateText and ImageUrl.